# Analytic geometry - historical & applied

Tags: self-learning

What would you suggest as good sources for a self-study of analytic geometry,
from the elementary properties of quadratic curves to curves of higher degree, with emphasis on historical development and practical applications in mechanics, astronomy and other fields?